# Like Banks, are there better service providers from Bitcoins banks? Can I Find a rating?

Tags: transactions, wallet, banks

I would like to purchase Bitcoins, I am looking and honestly do not know what I am looking at.  Is there a place to see how these Bitcoin places are rated? Services they provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a honest seller with low risks involved. Go for [Coinbase.com](https://www.coinbase.com) if you are in the US. You could check their gov issued licenses for buying and selling bitcoins here: https://www.coinbase.com/legal/licenses